# How to recover AWS windows instance reachability check failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS Windows instance status checks showing error and unable to connect via RDP.

Status Check -

Instance status checks
Error showing: "Instance reachability check failed"

I have tried stop and start - Not resolved
also rebooted the instance - Not resolved

Can you please help?

Comment: Verify that your security group has a rule that allows RDP access. For more information, see Create a security group.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshoot-connect-windows-instance.html

Comment: what kind of windows version you are using and in which region?Can you try stopping your instance and start again?

Comment: I used RDP  and port 3389 is allowed. But after stop / start - its not working anymore. Instance screenshot is  showing - https://prnt.sc/z6zh0b

Windows: 10 with MS SQL installed